# How to make spacy train faster on NER for Persian language

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, farsi

I have a blank model from `spacy`, in the `config file` I use the widget [Training Pipelines & Models](https://spacy.io/usage/training) with this config:

> Language = Arabic
>
> Components = ner
>
> Hardware = CPU
>
> Optimize for = accuracy

then in `config-file` I changed the:

```
[nlp]
lang = "ar"
```

to

```
[nlp]
lang = "fa"
```

because there is no pretrained `GPU (transformer)` for `persian-language`.

and as you know the `accuracy` type is very slow and I have **400,000** records.

this is my `config-file`

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
[system]
gpu_allocator = null

[nlp]
lang = "fa"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner"]
batch_size = 1000

[components]

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["ORTH", "SHAPE"]
rows = [5000, 2500]
include_static_vectors = true

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 256
depth = 8
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}

[corpora]

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
```

How can I make the training process faster?

Comment: Your statement that spaCy doesn't support Persian is incorrect. There are not pretrained pipelines, but for training your own model you can just select it from the dropdown in the quickstart when generating a config. The default Transformer is a multilingual one, so if possible it should be replaced with a Persian-specific one. https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart

Comment: @polm23: updated the OP's question

Comment: I don't know much about nlp and spacy. However I would like to know how you have trained your own models or datasets. Did you use annotator tools? If so please give me a guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To speed up training you have a few options.

**Change the evaluation frequency.** It's not in the config the widget generates, but there's an `eval_frequency` option - it should be filled in if you use `fill-config` as recommended. The default value is relatively low, and evaluation is slow. You should increase this value a lot if you have a large amount of training data.

**Use the `efficiency` presets instead of `accuracy`.** If speed is an issue then you should try this. For your pipeline, the relevant options are whether to include static vectors or not, and the width or depth of your tok2vec. Note this alone won't affect speed that much, but because it definitely reduces memory usage it can be usefully combined with the next option.

**Increase batch size.** In training the time to process a batch is relatively constant, so larger batches means fewer batches for the same data, which means faster training. How large a batch you can handle depends on the size of your documents and your hardware.

**Use less training data.** This is very rarely something that I'd recommend, but if you have 400,000 records you shouldn't need that many to get a good NER model. (How many classes do you have?) Try 10,000 to start with and see how your model performs, and scale up until you get the accuracy/speed tradeoff you want. This will also help you figure out if there is some kind of issue with your data more quickly.

For tips on faster inference (not training), see the [spaCy speed FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402).

Answer (score 1):

You might just be using one core of your CPU, as that is kind of the Python default iirc. I would look into parallelizing the job with joblib and increasing your chunk size.

See: https://prrao87.github.io/blog/spacy/nlp/performance/2020/05/02/spacy-multiprocess.html#Option-3:-Parallelize-the-work-using-joblib

Comment: That article is from 2020 and therefore addresses spaCy v2, while v3 of spaCy was released in 2021 and is what the asker is using. It is also not about training, which is harder to parallelize because you still have to resolve gradients.

Comment: @polm23, thanks for the corrections! Does this section of the new documentation refer to training and inference? It would seem so, but wanted to make sure. 

https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#multiprocessing

Comment: That section in the docs refers to inference only. `nlp.pipe` is for inference.